# Why can't this simple Dart code be compiled?

Tags: dart

Here is some simple Dart code:

```dart
class P {
  var name = myname();

  String myname() => "PPP";
}

main() {
  new P();
}
```

It reports this error when running:

```
Error: line 2 pos 14: illegal implicit access to receiver 'this'
  var name = myname();
             ^
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: No problem! We're all here to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're attempting to evaluate a non-static method in a static context (see note).  You can either mark the method as `static`:

```dart
class P {
  var name = myname();

  static String myname() => "PPP";
}
```

Or evaluate the code in a non-static context:

```dart
class P {
  var name;

  P() {name = myname();}

  static String myname() => "PPP";
}
```

**Note:** The concept of "static context" here is my mental model, which may or may not perfectly match how Dart works.  It may be more correct to note that `this` simply isn't available in a field initializer, explicitly or implicitly.

Comment: This is quite different from Java, why dart has this limitation?

Comment: @Freewind I couldn't say.  You could ask on one of the Google Groups forums if you're really curious.

Comment: There are a number of restrictions to avoid running arbitrary code at initialization time. The goals as I understand it are to make initialization safe (you can't access a partially build object) and fast.